# why do environment variables have String type instead of string slice in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, environment-variables

for immutable, constant strings we use `&str`. for example,

```
let url: &'static str = "yourUrl";
```

The `url` is a constant value and doesn't need to be modified. It's a reference to a sequence of UTF-8 bytes and we are just reading it here.

However, environment variables have `String` type:

```
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

dotenv().ok();

let api_key: String =
    env::var("Your_api_key").expect("API KEY NOT FOUND");
```

`String` is a growable, mutable, owned type in Rust. It's allocated on the heap and allows dynamic modification of its contents but environment variables are constant and loaded when the rust program starts. Why is it not type `&str`?

Comment: There's no obvious reason why it couldn't be `&str` but there is probably *some* reason why this decision was made. I'd expect `env::var` to have been laid down in a very early version of Rust, so if you really want to know you'll likely have to dig back through any RFC type discussion about it.

Comment: The environment of a process is a global resource but it is not constant, it can be changed with `env::set_var` or the equivalent C API. But if it were a `&str` it should point to immutable memory...

Comment: @rodrigo but it can't, because that memory does not meet the guarantee of str.

Answer (score 6):

> environment variables are constant and loaded when the rust program starts. Why is it not type &str?

Because envvars are *not* constant: `setenv(3)`, `unsetenv(3)`, and `putenv(3)` exist (as well as `clearenv(3)` in glibc).

Comment: … and you can also get a direct, non-constant pointer to the actual memory location holding the environment variables, and legally mutate that.

Comment: FWIW that is not true. While the return pointer of `getenv` is non-const, every specification document indicates that modifying its return value is not allowed, or plain says that it's an UB.

Comment: Sure, but you can directly access (and legally modify) `environ`/`_environ` on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Despite appearances `env::var` is not just a getter for a constant string. The set of environment variables is an os specific mutable set of variables. They can be updated by a process, (commonly as part of forking). And they are not guaranteed to be valid utf-8. As such `env::var` does two things: read the current state of the variable as an OSString, and then attempt to convert the OSString to String. As part of it it checks that its a valid string. That conversion must go into a buffer that is owned by the caller.

Comment: FWIW the latter part is not technically true, from an immutable shared reference to bytes, Rust is perfectly happy to validate the content in-place then return an `&str` e.g. [`OsStr::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str) or [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).

Comment: @Masklinn how does that method on windows  handle strings that encode differently in utf-8 and wtf-8?

Comment: And from_utf8 is no good because we do not have utf8, we made utf-16 or soothing else, and need to round trip it